# How to get HttpServletResponse object in restlet for GAE BlobStore serve

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, restlet

I'm using Restlet with GAE, and the GAE Blobstore API requires a HttpServletRequest object for uploading blobs and a HttpServletResponse object for serving them.  Is there any way to get the HttpServletResponse object from the restlet Response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the utility class org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServletUtils to get to the HttpServletRequest :

```
org.restlet.Request restletRequest = getRequest();
HttpServletRequest servletRequest = ServletUtils.getRequest(restletRequest);
```

and similar for the response :

```
org.restlet.Request restletResponse = getResponse();
HttpServletResponse servletResponse = ServletUtils.getResponse(restletResponse);
```

Comment: I created object successfully but now when I try to download file it throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: NO CONTENT exception.