# In-app handling of SubDomain with GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, restlet

How to handle subdomain in a GAE application? Is it possible that the app to distinguish from:

E.g.

`user1.xyz.com` and `user2.xyz.com` ? using Java code? Or should this be done with my domain hosting, like GoDaddy?  Or this can be done with a web framework like Spring or Restlet? Or I need to use both (GoDaddy + Spring or Restlet)?

I am using Restlet framework for my web app is it possible to do something like:

```
public class RootServerResource extends ServerResource {
  @Get("json")
  public String represent() {
    String username = getRequest().getSubDomain(); //  here!
    return "";
  }
}
```

Here are my questions:

- Is it possible for a single GAE app to handle multiple sub domains?
- If yes, is it possible to to set GAE subdomain to be a wildcard (*)
- Using Restlet how do I achieve to get subdomains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `HttpServletRequest` class you can use `getServerName()` to know the hostname that the client requested. [See the documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServerName()).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615450/how-to-get-httpservletresponse-object-in-restlet-for-gae-blobstore-serve) explains how to obtain the `HttpServletRequest` with Restlet :

> You can use the utility class org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServletUtils to get to the HttpServletRequest.

Now the complete code will be :

```
org.restlet.Request restletRequest = getRequest();
HttpServletRequest servletRequest = ServletUtils.getRequest(restletRequest);
String serverName = servletRequest.getServerName();
```

Comment: Actually what I need is I need to get the IP and domain of the client

Comment: Are you sure ? That's not what your question says. Anyway you can get the IP address and domain of the client through `getRemoteAddr()` and `getRemoteHost()` . Note that it is not always the IP address of the client, for example if he uses a proxy you will only see the proxy address.